# Libgdx - How to get coordinate of rotating object?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm studying Libgdx, and I have a small question: How can I get coordinate of rotating object? I search it in google, and I knew I must use Sprite, so I dont understand yet.

Any example fot it?

P/S: I writting a game. It have an object, when I click on the screen, this object move foward its front. How to resolved it?

Comment: I guess you are mix the view with the logic. While the view should only be the visual rapresentation of the game, the whole logic (including positon calculation etc.) should be separated.  
You need a class (lets call it `Entity`), which stores a `Vector2 position`. Manipulate this `Vector2` over time and draw a `Texture`, `Sprite`, whatever at the given `position`

Comment: You get the coordinate of a rotating object the exact same way as if it was a non-rotating object. I believe that's not your real question, so you should be a bit more clear.